# Vaadin Plugin for creation of Walkthrough/Tutorial mode directly in Webapp

Tags: java, vaadin

I've got a Vaadin webapp and want to provide a direct tutorial/walkthrough mode which shows hints for specific webapp areas, directly.

Imagine a webapp which has a menu bar and specific sub pages. In tutorial mode, when the user enters a specific sub page, then I'd like to draw a big arrow which points to a specific menu or UI component and a message text which explains something about it.

I already saw such embedded tutorial modes on some web pages. Is there a convenient possiblity for implementing this in combination with Vaadin? Are there any Vaadin plugins/components for that?

Comment: I mean something like this but on side of my Vaadin webapp (not by external supplier): https://inlinemanual.com/

Comment: This question does not really fit the SO guidelines, but nonetheless, you can try using the [wizards add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/wizards-for-vaadin) to give a guided tour with some screenshots (even simulate some parts of your application), or the [product tour add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/product-tour-add-on) which is somewhat similar to what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is exactly for what I am looking for! If you convert it into an answer, I'm going to accept it.